# How do I uninstall Phabricator

Tags: php, mysql, phabricator

I host a Phabricator instance on a Ubuntu machine.

How do I uninstall Phabricator totally, including all config files and settings.

I already removed all three folders cloned from git, and uninstalled mysql-server using
`sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove mysql-server`.

However, when I run `install_ubuntu.sh` to install back again, the old admin account, the log for Daemons logs, and the site settings are still there in website.

How can I remove all configuration and data completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem most likely is that uninstalling the MySQL server does not delete databases. You have a couple of options.

Probably the best way to delete the data would be to run Phabricator's `bin/storage destroy` command. This is the best approach, because it does not make any assumptions about how Phabricator stores its data (MySQL, files etc.). Install Phabricator, MySQL and all other dependencies again, and look for `bin/storage` in Phabricator installation directory.

Another way would be to install `mysql-server` and `mysql-client`, launching the `mysql` command line client and dropping all databases starting with `phabricator_`.

If you really want to mess with database files directly, you can find them in `/var/lib/mysql`.

Comment: so purge not remove the data? Is there any way remove configuration files  and data when uninstall a package

Comment: I'm not sure about the particulars, but I think the main idea is that `apt-get` only affects files installed with the package. `remove` deletes binary files, libraries etc., and `purge` additionally removes configuration files. However, this does not affect files created by the package (in this case, databases). The reasoning is similar to why uninstalling a text editor does not delete your documents.